# Am I related to my friend

Tags: terminology

My great great great grandfather’s frist wife had one child and I am his descendant.  My great great great grandfather remarried a woman who was the sister of a man that was the ancestor of my friend.
Is it a small word after all? are we related, eg. step cousins in law or the such. Just wondering

Comment: Two of your respective ancestors were step cousins - I think that's as clearly as it can be expressed.

Comment: Everybody is related through [some common ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_Eve). In practice, if the relationship is very tenuous you might not say "we are related", or if you said "we're related" someone might say "not really", but there's no hard-and-fast cut-off point.